# Is there a way to get cookies value from helper function which is located in lib folder of SvelteKit?

Tags: telegram-bot, sveltekit

I have a telegram bot code that is placed in separate file in lib folder. This file is imported in hooks.server.js (to initialize the bot once the app is started) and contains bot instance and events handlers. I need to get cookies value inside one of the handler function, but have no idea how to do that. Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Actually if you know how to initialize some unique key on particular page of the SvelteKit app and then access it from telegram bot lib file the question with cookies could be omitted.